# how to get privacy settings of a sharepoint site using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use Graph API to see if i can get privacy settings (public or private) of all SharePoint sites in my tenant, but i am not seeing any endpoint in the documentation that can provide that information, can you please help

i tried below

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?$select=siteCollection,webUrl&$filter=siteCollection/root%20ne%20null

then using siteid from above i tried
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/03164a2b-a288-486a-993e-c41454113e2a/settings